# Redux updating nested data [Immutable Update Patterns]

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, immutability

Can anyone help with this update pattern. I am not using any libraries like immer.

I have to update a nested object and the data looks like dis

**Sample data**

```
    { 
      isFetching: false
      data:{
            nba : {
                    stack :{
                            1:[]
                           }
                  }
           }
    }
```

**My Reducer**

```
 {
        ...state,
        isFetching: false,
        data: {
          ...state.data,
          [action.payload.team]: {
            ...state[action.payload.team],
            [action.payload.framework]: {
              ...state[action.payload.framework],
              [action.payload.build]: action.payload.resp
            }
          }
        }
 };
```

I am able to update until second level but unable to update third child.
can anyone throw a light on where i am missing it.

I put a demo on codesandbox.
https://codesandbox.io/s/todos-0ygrs

Click on collapse and inner collapse items. I am logging the changes for the state in the console below. As you can see at last level, build numbers are getting replaced with the new one's.

**Current Behaviour** *After you expand nba and all the three childs*

```
  {
    nba: {
           stack:{
                  3:[]
          }
  }
```

**Expected Behaviour:** *After you expand stack and all the three childs*

```
 {
    nba: {
           stack:{
                   1:[],
                   2:[],
                   3:[]
               }
         }
   }
```

Comment: @joseph.. nope, have you expanded all the children panels?..I dont see expected behaviour as mentioned above..it is just showing only 1 panel id which we expand at last   Ex: stack{ 1: [ ] } and it is updating to stack: { 2: [ ]} if we expand second panel.. where as i am looking for stack:{ 1:[ ], 2:[ ]}

Answer (score 1):

You probably have to use a [get helper](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/data-list/blob/master/lib.js#L1-L12) because you may try to set a part of state that doesn't exist yet.

With the get helper you can set the state like this:

```
const { team, framework, build, resp } = action.payload;
const newState = {
  ...state,
  isFetching: false,
  data: {
    ...get(state, ['data']),
    [team]: {
      ...get(state, ['data', team]),
      [framework]: {
        ...get(state, ['data', team, framework]),
        [build]: resp,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Somehow i figured out my mistake, Hope it helps someone in future

**Initial state should not be null, it should be empty object and update pattern should be in this manner**

```
 {
    ...state,
    isFetching: false,
    data: {
      ...state.data,
      [action.payload.team]: {
        ...state.data[action.payload.team],
        [action.payload.framework]: {
          ...state.data[action.payload.team][action.payload.framework],
          [action.payload.build]: action.payload.resp
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

**if it fails, then try this way**

```
let teamTemp = { ...state.data[action.payload.team]}

     {
        ...state,
        isFetching: false,
        data: {
          ...state.data,
          [action.payload.team]: {
            ...teamTemp ,
            [action.payload.framework]: {
              ...teamTemp[action.payload.framework],
              [action.payload.build]: action.payload.resp
            }
          }
        }
      };
```

I have forked my codesandbox and updated latest code.

- Old Code: https://codesandbox.io/s/todos-0ygrs

  New Code: https://codesandbox.io/s/todos-zqeki