# Push item to a nested object array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object with nested objects with the below structure, how can I dynamically add new items (`newData`) to the `cost3` array?

I have tried that but the new data isn't being pushed, what am I doing wrong?

```
const [file, setFile] = useState({})

setFile(file=> ({
      ...file,
      [cost3]: {
          ...file.cost3,
          newData
      }
}))
```

`File` object:

```
{
      "info": {

      },
      "client": {

      },
      "costs": {
        "cost1": 1,
        "cost2": 5,
        "cost3": [
          {
            "a": "test",
            "b": "test",
            "c": "test",
          },
          {
            "d": "test",
            "e": "test",
            "f": "test",
          },
         //etc..       
        ],
        "cost4": [
          {
            "l": "test",
            "n": "test",
            "m": "test",
          },
        //etc..
        ]
      }
    }
```

Comment: What is `[const3]` in setFile, I don't see you define the const3 variable anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const file = {
  "info": {

  },
  "client": {

  },
  "costs": {
    "cost1": 1,
    "cost2": 5,
    "cost3": [{
        "a": "test",
        "b": "test",
        "c": "test",
      },
      {
        "d": "test",
        "e": "test",
        "f": "test",
      },
      //etc..       
    ],
    "cost4": [{
        "l": "test",
        "n": "test",
        "m": "test",
      },
      //etc..
    ]
  }
}

const newData = { x: 'I am new' }

console.log(
  {
    ...file,
    costs: {
      ...file.costs,
      cost3: [
        ...file.costs.cost3,
        newData
      ]
    }
  }
)
```

Comment: If you see how state is initialezed `useState({})` you can conclude that `...file.costs.cost3,` will throw a "const3 of undefined" error. I would suggest using some sort of [get](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58335595/1641941) to make it less error prone.

Answer (score 2):

### Your code is incorrect.

Replace `[cost3]` with `cost3` and `{}` with `[]`, like so:

```
setFile(file=> ({
      ...file,
      costs: {
        ...file.costs,
        cost3: [
          ...file.costs.cost3,
          newData
        ]
      }
}))
```

Comment: Looks like OP is trying to set `file.const.const3` but since file is initialized with `{}` trying to spread file.const.const3 will throw because const is initially undefined. Maybe better to use some sort of [get](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58335595/1641941)

Answer (score 0):

You can try it using [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat).

```
cost3 = [];
const [file, setFile] = useState({});

setFile(file => ({
  cost3: file.cost3.concat(newData),
}));
```

Comment: I would suggest using concat instead of push because push will mutate the array.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `.push()` method to add item to object, for dynamic addition you can iterate through the array.